# How to integrate transmission into RobotHW

Tags: ros, ros-control, transmission

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have migrated our robot base driver to use ros_control.

That works well, execpt for the transmissions. There are transmissions in the URDF Model:

```
<transmission name="wheel_left_trans">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="wheel_left_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="left_motor">
    <mechanicalReduction>12</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
</transmission>
```

Is there a common practice on how to use this in the RobotHW?

The only example I know of is [this tutorial](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/wiki/transmission_interface). But there the transmission is not read from the URDF model.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202345/how-to-integrate-transmission-into-robothw/) by [Michael Stoll](https://answers.ros.org/users/12221/michael-stoll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a common practice on how to use this in the RobotHW?

Yes. Typically you would somehow populate the actuator interfaces when initializing your `RobotHW` specialization, and then use the `TransmissionInterfaceLoader` class to automatically populate your joint interfaces from the URDF + the actuator interfaces.

I thought there were no code examples available, but it turns out that I did write some doc back in the day. It's just not very visible. Please see the [`TransmissionInterfaceLoader` class code API](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/transmission_interface/html/c++/classtransmission__interface_1_1TransmissionInterfaceLoader.html).

The above only deals with populating interfaces. You would then need to actually propagate the transmissions in the read/write methods of your `RobotHW`. Please refer to the main [`transmission_interface` Doxygen page](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/transmission_interface/html/c++/index.html) for examples.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Michael Stoll](https://answers.ros.org/users/12221/michael-stoll/) on 2015-02-04**:
Thanks, TransmissionInterfaceLoader is great.
@All: You only need the propagation from the tranmission_interface example. The wrapping is handled by TransmissionInterfaceLoader!